# Type 5 errors when using ExportAsFixedFormat

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

It seems to work for everyone else, but my exportasfixedformat always calls up a type 5 error.

I've tried: similar code to others, checking everything has been dimmed, using _, and more but I just can't get my head around it.

```
Dim wordApp As Object
Dim wordDoc As Object
Dim newName As String
Dim FilE As String
Dim filePath As String

Public Sub MainCode()
filePath = "X:\Invoices\10.4.1 RFPOs\"
FilE = "X:\Invoices\10.4.1 RFPOs\Supporting Evidence Template v1.docx"
Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
wordApp.Visible = True
Set wordDoc = wordApp.documents.Open(FilE)
newName = "THIS SMELLS"
wordDoc.CustomDocumentProperties("PO_Item").Value = newName
wordDoc.Fields.Update
wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat outputfilename:=filePath & newName & ".pdf", 
exportformat:=wdExportFormatPDF
wordDoc.Close
wordApp.Quit
Set wordDoc = Nothing
Set wordApp = Nothing
```

End Sub

Run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure or argument.

Comment: Do you have a reference set to the Microsoft Word Object Library under *Tools* > *References*?

Comment: `wdExportFormatPDF` is defined in the Word type library - you need to use the underlying value of that named constant, or reference the library and use early binding / declare `wordApp As Word.Application`, `wordDoc As Word.Document`, and `Set wordApp = New Word.Application`.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have a reference set to the Microsoft Word Object Library under Tools > 
>   References? – BigBen 1 hour ago

THANKS BEN! I searched the list twice and thought that the office 16.0 reference was the correct one - it's a big list, and only after your comment went back again and found "word" was there the whole time :)

Answer (score 0):

if  reference to Word was there the whole time, Error 5 will also be raised  if `CustomDocumentProperties` "PO_Item" is not added. I reproduced error 5 on that line.

Make it

```
wordDoc.CustomDocumentProperties.Add _
    Name:="PO_Item", LinkToContent:=False, Value:=newName, _
    Type:=msoPropertyTypeString
```

Also keep in a line

```
wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat outputfilename:=filePath & newName & ".pdf", exportformat:=wdExportFormatPDF
```

and it is tested and working.